# SQL basic full-text search

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have not worked much with TSQL or the full-text search feature of SQL Server so bear with me.

I have a table nvarchar column (Col) like this:

```
       Col  ... more columns
Row 1: '1'
Row 2: '1|2'
Row 3: '2|40'
```

I want to do a search to match similar users.  So if I have a user that has a Col value of '1' I would expect the search to return the first two  rows.  If I had a user with a Col value of '1|2' I would expect to get Row 2 returned first and then Row 1.  If I try to match users with a Col value of '4' I wouldn't get any results.  I thought of doing a 'contains' by splitting the value I am using to query but it wouldn't work since '2|40' contains 4...

I looked up the documentation on using the 'FREETEXT' keyword but I don't think that would work for me since I essentially need to break up the Col values into words using the '|' as a break.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Why wouldn't `CONTAINS` work?

Comment: I want an exact match with each portion of the string.  The '|' is essentially a break between values.  '2' and '2|40' should match but not '4' and '2|40'

Comment: do you only have 2 values or could row 4 have a value like 2|5|41 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store values like '1|2' in a field to store 2 values. If you have a maximum of 2 values, you should use 2 fields to store them. If you can have 0-many values, you should store them in a new table with a foreign key pointing to the primary key of your table..

If you only have max 2 values in your table. You can find your data like this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(3) = '1'

SELECT * 
FROM <table> 
WHERE @s IN( 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '|', '.'), 1),  
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '|', '.'), 2) 
    --,PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '|', '.'), 3) -- if col can contain 3 
    --,PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '|', '.'), 4) -- or 4 values this can be used
  )
```

Parsename can handle max 4 values. If 'col' can contain more than 4 values use this

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(3) = '1'

SELECT * 
FROM <table> 
WHERE '|' + col + '|' like '%|' + @s + '|%'
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought.  I am using a CMS and this is how it stores the data.  I will try your second solution but if it doesn't perform well enough I will just add a new table and change everything to use it.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Need to mix this in with a case for when there is no | but this returns the left and right hand sides

```
      select left('2|10', CHARINDEX('|', '2|10') - 1)
      select right('2|10', CHARINDEX('|', '2|10'))
```

Comment: you are going to get some problems with this solution. Problem 1 the 'RIGHT' part only works if there is 1 more character on the right side than on the left side of the column. Problem 2 the 'LEFT' part will give an error if there is no '|' in the column

Comment: @t-clausen-dk  As I stated "Need to mix this in with a case for when there is no | but this returns the left and right hand sides".